# MIX issues on Windows

Tags: mix, windows, linux

I've been involved with Ethereum for few months and am getting really excited about the functionalities it offers. Actually I'm trying to develop some contracts and deploy on the blockchain.

I use both Linux ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 for my Ethereum tests and hacks.

I'm just getting this nasty issue with Mix - every time I try to open a new project it freezes and crashes.

I also get these errors on startup:

http://pastebin.com/jJTzDVpT

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Comment: Any chance to build Mix and other stuff of ++eth from source in windows and maybe avoid this error?

Comment: Also i see that Mix uses electron to work am i right?

Comment: have you built from source? seems that it cannot find Qt.
does it crash with ubuntu or windows?