# Why can't I open Mix?

Tags: bug, mix, mac-osx, ide

I've downloaded mix for OS X from here:
https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases

but every time I try to open it, it stops, and I get the error "mix quit unexpectedly"

I've tried downloading different versions, but the same thing happens every time.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's a bug I think. Here's the [same issue on windows](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1787/87).

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the binary from [here](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/osx-dmg.html) and it works on my system (OSX El Capitan). Mix is under hard development as I understand so a thing might be working today, but broken tomorrow. Just have a bit of patience (I know it's frustrating ;) ).

If that doesn't work for you, maybe you could also try [homebrew](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/osx-homebrew.html). Haven't tried it myself but it should be as easy as:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install cpp-ethereum
brew linkapps cpp-ethereum
```

Or ...

```
brew install cpp-ethereum --with-gui
```

If none of these things work consider installing [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/). I find they are more pleasant to work with but don't provide the debugging options that Mix has.

Comment: Please try not to post link-only answers. Could you consider adding more details for instance on how to install Mist through homebrew?